# About apache websocket issue, web page is not working properly

Tags: apache, websocket

I installed a NAS in my home host, and I also used apache reverse proxy for a project named V2rayA. Now on the public network, the webpage can be accessed normally. But there is a bug. The bug picture is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdW3Z.png).

I know this is the reason why websocket is not set, but I'm newbie and I can't fix it. How can I setup my websocket?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLProxyEngine on
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /home/exploit/Apache/1.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /home/exploit/Apache/2.key
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"
        <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass /v2ray/ http://127.0.0.1:2017/
        ProxyPassReverse /v2ray/ http://127.0.0.1:2017/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I add and if possible please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

After I mapped this to the public network, it was still inaccessible, and then I knew that .websocket runs on port 443 by default, but the home network cannot use port 443, so this happens. You can use other methods to forward websockets